# <div align="left" class="abcd"> css old method

Tags: css

When I use the validator, it says that

```
the align attribute on the div element is obsolete. Use CSS instead
```

What do I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use style attribute. For example:

```
<div style="text-align:center"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a `text-align` declaration to a style block for `.abcd`:

```
.abcd { text-align: left; }
```

or set the style of the `div` itself locally:

```
<div class="abcd" style="text-align: left;">
```

Comment: you need not use "text-align: left;" if you already handle it in class.

Comment: ...which is why I said *or* for the second suggestion :D

Answer (score 1):

Do not use

```
<div align='left'>lefty</div>
```

Use

```
<div style='text-align:left'>lefty</div>
```

Comment: floating left is completely different than aligning left - align left aligns the CONTENT - floating floats the ELEMENT

Answer (score 0):

Don't

```
1] <div align='left'></div>
```

Do

```
1] <div style="text-align:left"></div>
```

OR

```
2] .divClass { text-align: left; }
   <div class="divClass"></div>
```